# The missing piece of the puzzle: how to run Rails C on an AWS ECS Fargate environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

Setting up a Rails app on AWS Fargate has been somewhat of a struggle, but the more I tried, the more I learned. I now have multiple tasks running multiple parts of my environment (websever, worker and a task queue). The last piece of the puzzle is establishing `rails console` access to this environment.

I've read articles on Medium: https://engineering.loyaltylion.com/running-an-interactive-console-on-amazon-ecs-c692f321b14d, but it seems to be depending on EC2 instead of Fargate.

Then I found this post on SO: [How to launch a rails console in a Fargate container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55845582/how-to-launch-a-rails-console-in-a-fargate-container)

It seems that the solution is to set-up a VPN into my VPC. Since I'm not an expert on networking, I was wondering if there is a clear guide on how to set-up a VPN to my VPN on Mac?

And if I finally succeed with setting up this VPN, how would I then be running `rails c`? Is there some AWS CLI command I need to run? Do I need to define a separate task that runs the command... or?

Answer (score 0):

To run rails console on a container running on fargate, you would need to run a `docker exec`, but it is not supported yet. There is an open issue for this: https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/187

Comment: Thanks, so would you say that currently it is impossible, or at least not easy and straightforward?

Comment: It is not impossible. There are some solutions In the issue, but they are not trivial and some introduce security holes. This case is very similar to yours, but the guy did it with Django: https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/187#issuecomment-490347856